# How to change the href of a button depending on whether a class is active or not

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am struggling to use Js and Jquery to change the href of a button depending on whether a class is active or not. I am still new to Javascript so I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about this but any advice on how to get my current code working properly would be awesome.
Here is my code..

```
if ($("#carousel-item-1").hasClass('active')) {
$("#portfolio-btn").attr("href", "https...");
}

if ($("#carousel-item-2").hasClass('active')) {
    $("#portfolio-btn").attr("href", "https...");
}

if ($("#carousel-item-3").hasClass('active')) {
    $("#portfolio-btn").attr("href", "https...");
}
```

The code works for carousel-item-1. It sucessfully changes the buttons empty href attribute to the desired website address. But what can I do to get the other two working? The active class DOES change on the other carousel items so that's not the problem but my button doesn't change the href depending on which carousel item is active. It just stays at the first carousel items link. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, it's hard to advise, but basically you need to apply your if statement logic when a new slide is presented. At that time, the slide will be active and you can apply the attribute.

If you're using the jQuery carousel there is a event called `slid.bs.carousel` that is fired when a new slide transitions in. For example....

```
$("#myCarousel").on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    // The carousel has finished sliding from one item to another
    checkForActive()
  });

function checkForActive() {
 if ($("#carousel-item-1").hasClass('active')) {
    $("#portfolio-btn").attr("href", "https...");
 }

 if ($("#carousel-item-2").hasClass('active')) {
    $("#portfolio-btn").attr("href", "https...");
 }

 if ($("#carousel-item-3").hasClass('active')) {
    $("#portfolio-btn").attr("href", "https...");
 }
}
```